# Unsure if my Android app is sending valid POST requests

Tags: android, http, post, flask, sinatra

I have an app that at the moment I'm just sending some dummy data through a POST request to a Flask server.  The flask server is not seeing the post data.  When I send it to a sinatra server the post data is there no problem.

Android Code:

```
URL url = new URL(imageRequests[0].getUrl());
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
System.out.println(urlParameters);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    print request.form
    return "Uploaded"
```

Flask Output:

```
Loading from savePath test.tree
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
ImmutableMultiDict([])
10.100.85.69 - - [25/Jul/2014 17:09:07] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Sinatra Code:

```
post '/' do
  puts params
  "Uploaded"
end
```

Sinatra Output:

```
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-07-25 17:07:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=18674 port=4567
{"param1"=>"a", "param2"=>"b", "param3"=>"c"}
10.100.85.69 - - [25/Jul/2014 17:07:35] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 0.0053
10.100.85.69 - - [25/Jul/2014:17:07:34 BST] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 12
- -> /
```

I'm really confused as to why Sinatra is getting the post data, but flask isn't.  My only guess is that the POST request from android is not quite right and that sinatra is more forgiving on that.

Is this the case?

Edit: Output from netcat listening over the port

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 7 Build/KTU84P)
Host: 10.100.85.210:5000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

1b
?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c
0
```

Comment: can you try changing `param1=a&param2=b&param3=c` to `?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c`? That might have an effect

Comment: I would try to use tcpdump (or similar) to monitor the IP data on the net. You can do this from a 3rd party PC if needed, as long as it's on the same network. This way you can see exactly what is being sent to Flask and whether Flask is responding at all, which is a good first step.

Comment: I still get ImmutableMultiDict([])

Comment: jhulme: are you saying the app dies before sending? that wasn't clear.

Comment: Added output from netcat to the original question.

Comment: rivimey: The android is stays alive.  Both servers seem to stay alive as well.  Sinatra can see the post data but flask can't

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to this.  It seems to have been a problem with chunking the output

```
URL url = new URL(imageRequests[0].getUrl());
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String urlParameters = "param1=value&param2=value";
System.out.println(urlParameters);
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(urlParameters);
writer.close();
```